# Why are the images not properly separated?

Tags: html, css

I have searched and tweek around and the last image still shows up very close to the second.  This is a very simple responsive web layout that, for some mistake, it is not displaying properly.  this keeps asking me for more details but I have no more details to give.

```css
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.5;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #f4f4f4;
}


/* Global */

.container {
    widows: 80%;
    margin: auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.button_1 {
    height: 38px;
    background: #e8491d;
    border: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
}


/* Header */

header {
    background: #35424a;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding-top: 30px;
    min-height: 70px;
    border-bottom: #e8491d 4px solid;
}

header a {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 16px;
}

header li {
    float: left;
    display: inline;
    padding: 0 20px 0 20px;
}

header #branding {
    float: left;
}

header #branding h1 {
    margin: 0;
}

header nav {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 12px;
}

header .current a {
    color: #e8491d;
    font-weight: bold;
}

header a:hover {
    color: #cccccc;
    font-weight: bold;
}


/* Showcase */

#showcase {
    min-height: 400px;
    background: url('../Assets/for\ rent.jpg') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    text-align: center;
    color: #3433FF;
}

#showcase h1 {
    margin-top: 100px;
    font-size: 55px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#showcase p {
    font-size: 20px;
}


/* For Tenants */

#cozy {
    padding: 15px;
    background: #35424a;
}

.button_1 {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
}


/*Boxes*/

#boxes {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#boxes .box {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
    padding: 10px;
}

#main {
    margin-top: 20px;
}

#main .box {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    width: 33%;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

#main .box assets {
    width: 100px;
}


/*Footer*/

footer {
    padding: 20px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #e8491d;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <meta name="description" content="Properties for lease">
    <meta name="keywords" content="lakeland, oldsmar, lutz">
    <meta name="author" content="SAGS PROPERTIES LLC">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>SAGS PROPERTIES</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="./css/style.css" />
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="branding">
                <h1><span>SAGS Properties LLC</span></h1>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <ul>
                    <li class="current"><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="lutz.html">Lutz</a></li>
                    <li><a href="oldsmar.html">Oldsmar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="lakeland.html">Lakeland</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>

    <section id="showcase">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>Well Managed Properties</h1>
            <p>In Lutz, Oldsmar and Lakeland</p>

        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="cozy">
        <div class="container">
            <button type="submit" class="button_1">Tenants Click Here</button>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section id="boxes">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="box">
                <img src="./Assets/Entrance Lutz.jpg">
                <h3>Lutz</h3>
                <p>Lakeview at Calusa Trace</p>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="box">
                    <img src="./Assets/Entrance Lakeland.jpg">
                    <h3>Lakeland</h3>
                    <p>Cobblestone Landing</p>
                </div>
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="box">
                        <img src="./Assets/Entrance Oldsmar.jpg">
                        <h3>Oldsmar</h3>
                        <p>Gardens at Forrest Lakes</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
    </section>

    <footer>
        <p>SAGS PROPERTIES LLC &copy; 2018</p>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

There are no more details to give.  Making a question is as frustrating as learning this!!!

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to Stack Overflow. The question prompt is asking you for more details, and from a reader's perspective, I would say it's likely right. You included your code, which is great, but "the last image still shows up very close to the second [...]  it is not displaying properly" is hard for me to understand as someone trying to answer your question. It would help if you could describe what it's currently doing, what you want it to do instead, and what you've tried so far but hasn't worked. For UI issues, consider including a screenshot :)

Comment: The three divs with class "container" are nested inside each other, is that by design? And you use `float`, but not `clear`, that doesn't sound right. Also, `80%` is not a valid value for `widows`; run your code through a validator.